# Create admin user MongoDB not possible

Tags: mongodb

When I am trying to follow the tutorial by typing

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db1
```

console responds with

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db1
2017-03-03T14:43:54.019+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1776 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db1 64-bit host=Tim-V5
2017-03-03T14:43:54.020+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2017-03-03T14:43:54.021+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.2
2017-03-03T14:43:54.021+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3f76e40c105fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b
2017-03-03T14:43:54.022+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
2017-03-03T14:43:54.023+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-03-03T14:43:54.023+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-03-03T14:43:54.023+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-03-03T14:43:54.023+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2017-03-03T14:43:54.024+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-03-03T14:43:54.024+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-03-03T14:43:54.025+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/data/db1" } }
2017-03-03T14:43:54.025+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db1 not found., terminating
2017-03-03T14:43:54.026+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-03-03T14:43:54.026+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-03-03T14:43:54.027+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-03-03T14:43:54.027+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Even I already have created folder with

```
mkdir C:\data\db
```

and checked that it exists!

Following with

```
mongo --port 27017
```

It responds with

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/
MongoDB server version: 3.4.2
Server has startup warnings:
2017-03-03T10:02:59.647+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-03-03T10:02:59.647+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-03-03T10:02:59.647+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-03-03T10:02:59.647+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

I am using windows 10, how can I solve this? It's rather frustating

Comment: are you sure that `/data/db1` is a valid path in windows ? did you try with `mongod --port 27017 --dbpath="C:\data\db1" ` ?

Comment: an did you `mkdir C:\data\db`  or `mkdir C:\data\db1` ?

Comment: I tried with both mkdir, and went with port and then now I get shutting down code 48.

Thinking that mkdir C:\data\db1 worked I typed mongod and it returns with down code 100 again! So it seems pathing is at fault?

Comment: what's the output of : `mongod --port 27017 --dbpath C:\data\db1` ?

Comment: It's too long to paste here but it's shutting down code 48 that shows up! Or I can pm you the output?! Thanks for having patience to help me out

Comment: I don't know if you still have the problem but yes we can start a chat